# mmv_stats_interval_start usage example in c

Tags: performance, frameworks

I am using MMV libraries provided by Performance Co-Pilot (PCP) framework. I need to reset the value in the MMV instance on a regular interval basis. I came across the mmv_stats_interval_start() api of PCP. Please explain how this api is working and how to get notification when the interval is elapsed.

```
mmv_stats_interval_start(void *addr, pmAtomValue *value,
    const char *metric, const char *instance)
{
 if (addr) {
    if (value == NULL)
        value = mmv_lookup_value_desc(addr, metric, instance);
    if (value) {
        struct timeval tv; 
        __pmtimevalNow(&tv);
        mmv_inc_value(addr, value, -(tv.tv_sec*1e6 + tv.tv_usec));
    }   
 }   
 return value;
}
```

An example in the github page of PCP is [mmv_genstats.c](https://github.com/performancecopilot/pcp/blob/master/qa/src/mmv_genstats.c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mmv_stats_interval_start` function pairs with `mmv_stats_interval_end` to accumulate time intervals (microseconds) between matching pairs of those calls.  See for example http://git.pcp.io/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=pcp.git;a=blob;f=qa/src/mmv_genstats.c;hb=HEAD

MMV is not about notifications, only about efficiently exposing internal statistics of the program that uses `-lpcp_mmv`.  Notifications would have to arise from another PCP client such as `pmie`.

Comment: How can I get the interval value when mmv_stats_interval_end is called? Why is the instance "value" ( from the code in question ) is 1 till mmv_stats_interval_end is called ?

Comment: The (start-to-end) interval length will be added to the metric value after the `_end` function is called.  Between the `_start` and `_end` calls, the metric value is not really appropriate to read (so is a race condition).